# SMTP :mail sending failed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Here is my settings for sending the mail using SMTP

```
 $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'example', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
 );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $data = "Username:".$_POST['username']."\n\nPassword:".$_POST['password']."\n\n";
        $message="Your login details for Spotmyticket Agent portal\n\n". $data."\n\n";

        $message.="Click here to login<a href='http://root5solutions.com/agentspotmyticket/'>login</a>";

        $this->email->from('admin@spotmyticket.in','SpotMyticket');
        $this->email->to('example@gmail.com');

        $this->email->subject('Spotmyticket Agentportal login details');

        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send()
```

This is the error message i'm getting

> hello: 220-p3plcpnl0950.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2
>   Fri, 29 Jan 2016 00:01:29 -0700  220-We do not authorize the use of
>   this system to transport unsolicited,  220 and/or bulk e-mail. The
>   following SMTP error was encountered:
>   220-p3plcpnl0950.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Fri, 29
>   Jan 2016 00:01:29 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system
>   to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.  Unable to send
>   email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail
>   using this method. User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   12:31:24 +0530 From: "SpotMyticket" 
>   Return-Path:  To: shamonsha665@gmail.com
>   Subject:
>   =?UTF-8?Q?Spotmyticket=20Agentpo?==?UTF-8?Q?rtal=20logi?==?UTF-8?Q?n?= =?UTF-8?Q?=20details?= Reply-To: "admin@spotmyticket.in"  X-Sender: admin@spotmyticket.in X-Mailer:
>   CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID:
>   <56ab0e449ee15@spotmyticket.in> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_56ab0e449ee57"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_56ab0e449ee57 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: Did you read the error? *"We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. Unable to send email using PHP SMTP"*

Comment: It means that Google isn't allowing you to send out mails thew way you're trying to do it. You should consider using a service specifically for that purpose like [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/).

Comment: Please contact your hosting provider and they will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

gmail smtp not working properly,its better to use own domain smtp details